# sql isnull with string as option

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this portion of the query where I'm doing this.

```
FROM #Table2 WHERE Attribute = ISNULL('+@Attrb+', Attribute)) AS D
```

Obviously this isn't working for me as @Attr can bring in a string or can be empty. is there a better way to handle this? 
What I need is, this a parameter that is passed to this stored procedure. There are two possible choices (or a third one is empty). I'm allowing the users to type it in. How would you tackle this?

Thanks.

Comment: The [ISNULL function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) does the following: Checks whether the first parameter `IS NULL`; if it is it returns the second parameter otherwise the first. Since your first parameter isn't `NULL` it will always return the second. GL.

Comment: If you want to check @attrb variable value for null you can use query like this: `WHERE (@Attrb IS NOT NULL AND Attribute = @Attrb)`

Comment: Just to clarify my goal, I'd like to accept null values and two other text strings. if user supplied nothing(an empty string), I will display all records with no filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM #Table2 ' + ISNULL('WHERE Attribute = ''' + NULLIF(@Attrb,'') + '''', '') + ') AS D
```

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (Attribute VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES
('Id'),('Class'),('Name')

DECLARE @Attrb VARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

--Attrb is NULL
SET @SQL = ' SELECT * FROM #Table2 ' + ISNULL('WHERE Attribute = ''' + NULLIF(@Attrb,'') + '''', '')
EXEC(@SQL)

/*Result

  Attribute
  ---------
  Id
  Class
  Name
*/

--Give Attrb a value
SET @Attrb = 'Class'
SET @SQL = ' SELECT * FROM #Table2 ' + ISNULL('WHERE Attribute = ''' + NULLIF(@Attrb,'') + '''', '')
EXEC(@SQL)

/*Result

  Attribute
  ---------
  Class
*/
```

Comment: Just to clarify my goal, I'd like to accept null values and two other text strings. if user supplied nothing(an empty string), I will display all records with no filtering.

Comment: `NULLIF(@Attrb,'')` would solve the empty string problem

Comment: does a NULL value select records that have a NULL Attribute value? @Eclipse

Comment: there are no null attribute values. it's either 'component' or 'non comp'. So when the user supplies nothing (empty string), I want all records displayed, in other words, that where statement needs to be overlooked. just allowing the users to do filtering. If I can have a drop down for them to select from, that would be even  better.

Comment: It should work for you then.. If `@Attrb` is NULL or Empty the where statement will be exclude from the query

Comment: Careful here. You have your NULLIF outside the dynamic string portion which mean you will end up adding the first portion of your string and NULL so if @Attrb IS NULL you will have the value of your SQL variable being NULL.

Comment: @SeanLange that's actually the point.. that would exclude the entire 'WHERE' part because it would return null instead of a concatenated string.. then ISNULL would convert that NULL to ''

Comment: Not quite. You would be doing this. 'select *' + NULL which means the entire dynamic sql string will be NULL

Comment: NULLIF should be inside the ISNULL function.. unless i missed something

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked. Dynamic sql indeed sucks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated what version of SQL server you are using, but if you are using 2012 or later, you might want to check [iif](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh213574(v=sql.110).aspx)

Example for testing:

```
declare @Attrib varchar(20)

set @Attrib = NULL

select iif(@Attrib is null,'Null Result',@Attrib)
```

Comment: Using SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the string literals are doing in there. I am pretty sure you want something like this.

```
WHERE Attribute = ISNULL(@Attrb, Attribute)
```

Or if you are trying to deal with NULL or an empty string you can use NULLIF

```
WHERE Attribute = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Attrb, ''), Attribute)
```

--EDIT--

Modifying this to work with dynamic sql is pretty straight forward.

```
'WHERE Attribute = ISNULL(NULLIF(' + ISNULL(@Attrb, Attribute) + ', ''''), Attribute)'
```

Comment: i might be wrong but it looks like portion of a dynamic sql.. put a `'` before FROM and it would make more sense

Comment: I didn't see any indication from the OP that this is dynamic sql but the ' + stuff definitely makes it look like that is a possibility.

Comment: Sean, I am using dynamic sql. so I try your solution, it works as standard sql statement but trying to get this to work in my dynamic statement.